# Select2 destroy works on fiddle but not on another server

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-select2

This question seems weird, but this is what I'm facing. A table that has 2 dropdowns which select2 is attached. We should destroy the select2 before cloning it and then using it again, this is what I have done in my codes. As result, the codes work on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cwp2d7gq/1/ However, the same codes are not working on this link: https://gicrerd.com/utilitaire/test.

Does anyone have an idea of what can be the issue with that?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-sm table-striped mb-0">
<thead>
<tr class="bg-th">
<th>
Country
</th>
<th scope="col">
Towns
</th>

</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="form-select" onChange="center_area_on_change(this);">
<option value=""></option>
<option>Country 1</option>
<option>Country 2</option>
<option>Country 3</option>
<option>Country 4</option>
</select>
</td>
<td style="width:280px;display:block">

<select style='width:100%' onChange="getTarifDataSeguroPrivado(this);">
<option></option>
<option>Town 1</option>
<option>Town 2</option>
<option>Town 3</option>
<option>Town 4</option>
<option>Town 5</option>
</select>


</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
function center_area_on_change (el) {
console.log(el);
}



function getTarifDataSeguroPrivado(dropDown) {
addRow();
}

function addRow() {
$('table select').select2('destroy');
var tableBody = $('table').find("tbody");
var trLast = tableBody.find("tr:last");
var trNew = trLast.clone();

const lastSelectedCountryIndex = trLast.find('select').eq(0).find('option:selected').index();

trNew.find('select').eq(0).find('option').eq(lastSelectedCountryIndex).prop('selected', true);

trLast.after(trNew);
$('table select').select2();
}

$('table select').select2();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is due to the fact that you are duplicating your HTML element IDs. HTML element IDs must be unique; but each time you clone and append a row, you are creating duplicate IDs for the row and the two select elements. I recommend not using IDs in any elements that are cloned.

Comment: You are right man. This was the issue. Thank you so much. Actually, fiddle does not care about the cloning id, that's why it works on it.